# window.open() opening a tab instead of a window in Chrome using user input as url source

Tags: javascript, window.open

Not matter what I try, this code is still opening in a new tab.  Any ideas on how to modify this to make a new window open?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Cast Challonge</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $('#button').click(function(e) {  
            var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
            window.open("http://challonge.com/"+inputvalue+"/module?theme=5928&show_final_results=0&multiplier=0.3&show_tournament_name=1&scale_to_fit=1"),"_blank","width=1323,height=816";
    
        });
    });
    </script> 
    </head>
     <body>
    
           <input type="text" value="" id="input"> 
           <button type="button" id="button">Submit Tournament ID</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Typo.  The additional arguments to `window.open` aren't being passed to it, they're just being stated afterward.  When calling a function, include all arguments to that function within the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the correct answer in case anyone ever needs this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
        <head>
            <title>Cast Challonge</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
        
            $('#button').click(function(e) {  
                var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
                window.open(("http://challonge.com/"+inputvalue+"/module?theme=5928&show_final_results=0&multiplier=0.3&show_tournament_name=1&scale_to_fit=1"),"_blank","width=1323,height=816";)
        
             });
        });
        </script> 
         </head>
         <body>
        
               <input type="text" value="" id="input"> 
               <button type="button" id="button">Submit Tournament ID</button>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change '_blank' with your new window name. Example: 'New Window Test'